# Hibernate Criteria - Date Comparison is Not Returning Correct Results

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, orm

I am trying to retrieve a set of records that occur within a date range provided by user input. For some reason the criteria is not returning any results even though there are records that should match.

Model property and sample data:

```
@Column(name="date")
private Date date;

mysql> select * from student_interaction where id = X \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                 id: 23828
                 date: 2015-08-07 00:00:00
                 student_id: 2725
                 ... other columns ommitted
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Criteria implementation:

```
List<StudentInteraction> returnList = new ArrayList<StudentInteraction>();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StudentInteraction.class);
    if(userID > 0) {
        List<Number> criteriaInList = new ArrayList<Number>();
        criteriaInList = session.createSQLQuery("select student_id from advisor_student where advisor_id = :userID").setInteger("userID", userID).list();
        if(criteriaInList != null && criteriaInList.size() > 0) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.in("student.id", criteriaInList));
        }
    }
    criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("date", startDate));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("date", endDate));
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    returnList = criteria.list();
    return returnList;
```

Parameter values:

- startDate: Wed Aug 15 00:00:00 PST 14 (Date)
- endDate: Thu Aug 15 00:00:00 PST 15 (Date)
- criteriaInList: (1521, 1840, 1852, 1914, 5431, 10748, 29017, 8056, **2725**, 5505)

As you can see, the record's date falls within the provided *startDate* and *endDate*, and the record's student_id value is contained in the *criteriaInList* set. Does anyone have an idea why the returnList comes out to be [] (empty)?

Comment: Would you mind checking with the hard-coded `id` first? In your `criteria.add(Restrictions.in("student.id", criteriaInList))` replace `criteriaInList` for `new String[] { "2725" }` and see what happens

Comment: First, thanks for your comment. However, I have the same result using the hardcoded list. The problem seems to be independent of the criteriaInList restriction, because even when it never enters the (userID > 0) condition the result is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running generated sql with parameter values directly on database?
Are those start/end date GE and LT values satisfying the query?

You might just want to start with removing condition and start/end date criteria, and keep adding one-one criteria at a time.

Comment: Per your suggestion I only added the ``criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("date", startDate));`` restriction. It returns all of the StudentInteraction records regardless of whether the *date* property is GE than the startDate param. Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: How about the sql generated off of the criteria? Does that also bring all records?